# Why isn't my search icon fetching the API?

Tags: javascript, html, api, dom

I added a search Icon to my code, but now I need it to fetch the results in the API. I assigned it an id so I can access it but it's not working. What newbie mistake am I making?

```js
const searchForm = document.querySelector('form');
const searchResultDiv = document.querySelector('.search-result');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
let searchQuery='';
const searchIcon = document.getElementById('search-icon');

searchForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchQuery = e.target.querySelector('input').value;
    fetchAPI();
}) 

 searchIcon.addEventListener('click', (search) => {
    searchQuery = search.target.querySelector('input').value;
    fetchAPI();
})
```

```html
<head>
 <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<div class="container">
            <div class="logo" style="cursor: pointer">
                <img src="/Images/logo img.png">
                <h1 class="brand">Recipe App</h1>
            </div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Find Yummy Recipes...">
                <i class='bx bx-search' id="search-icon" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
            </form>
            <div class="search-result">
                 <!-- <div class="item">
                    <img src="/Images/Food-1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="food-details">
                        <h1 class="title">This is a Recipe</h1>
                        <a class="view-button" href="#">View Recipe</a>
                    </div>
                    <p class="item-data">Calories: 120</p>
                </div>    -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Define "not working". What's `fetchAPI`? In general I wouldn't use a global reference for the search data--retrieve it at the last possible moment.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below demonstrates how you can assign two event listeners (`'click'` and `'submit'`) to the `body` of the `document`. The `if` condition in the callback function turns it into a "delegated" event handling: the action will unfold only if the `sIcon` element was `click`-ed or the `submit` event was triggered (e. g. by hitting the return key after entering text into the input field).

As @DaveNewton remarked in a comment already, you should evaluate the `inp.value` as late as possible and not communicate it through a global variable but rather as an argument to the `fetchAPI()` function.

```js
const sIcon = document.getElementById('search-icon'),
  inp=document.querySelector("input");
 
['click','submit'].forEach(ty=>document.body.addEventListener(ty,ev=> {
  ev.preventDefault();
  if(ev.type=='click'&&ev.target==sIcon||ev.type=='submit')
    fetchAPI(inp.value);
}));

function fetchAPI(pat){
 console.log(`fetching data with pattern: ${pat}`);
}
```

```html
<head>
 <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<div class="container">
        <div class="logo" style="cursor: pointer">
            <img src="/Images/logo img.png">
            <h1 class="brand">Recipe App</h1>
        </div>
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Find Yummy Recipes...">
            <i class='bx bx-search' id="search-icon" style="cursor: pointer;"></i>
        </form>
        <div class="search-result">
             <!-- <div class="item">
                <img src="/Images/Food-1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="food-details">
                    <h1 class="title">This is a Recipe</h1>
                    <a class="view-button" href="#">View Recipe</a>
                </div>
                <p class="item-data">Calories: 120</p>
            </div>    -->
        </div>
    </div>
```